# Why I got 400 Bad Request on almost every input?

Tags: python, bad-request

In this code I ask user to input URL, then got access to the site and print all data from there.

```
import socket 
import urllib.parse
urluser = input('Enter -')
count = 0

host = urluser.split('/')[2]

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect((host, 80))

cmd = ('GET '+urluser+' HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n').encode()

mysock.send(cmd)

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    
    if len(data) < 1:
        break    
    print(data.decode(),end='') 

mysock.close()
```

For most sites i got **400 Bad Request** errors (f.e https://help.3dhubs.com/help-center/how-to-get-a-quote)

For some **301 Moved Permanently** though it is OK https://www.avito.ru/

And in rare cases it works - **200 OK** http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt

I tried to change port 80/443 and HTTP/1.0/HTTP/1.1/2.0 but it didn't help

Comment: Which sites are you getting bad request on?

Comment: for example - https://golfwang.com/

Comment: 400 Bad request means the query parameters are incorrect. Do you have a link to the API documentation?

Comment: Which API documentation? I know what the bad request is. I'm trying to solve it for a lot of hours

Comment: I understood how to do it wuth urlib library though though not with socket